# Echo value using php after getting ajax result and loading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello this is my js code which all my code in the same php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {

        $.post({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'html',
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>",
            data: {cid: $("#customer_Id").val()},


            complete: function(){
            } ,
            success: function(html){
                alert(html);


            }

        });

    });
    return false;
});
```

Secondly this is my html and php code

```
 <div class="row">


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 toppad">

            <div id="customerFrm">


            <input id="customer_Id" name="customer_Id" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">


                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="submit" value="search" onclick="$('#PataintInfo').removeClass('hidden');">Go!</button>

            </div><!-- /form -->


    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->



</div>

<div id="PataintInfo" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 toppad hidden">


<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Pataint Info</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="customerq_no" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" align="center">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td id="pid"><?php var_dump($_POST)?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gender</td>
                        <td>Male</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date of Birth</td>
                        <td>01/24/1988</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Mobile</td>
                        <td>Metro Manila,Philippines</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Service</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="roomlist">
                                <option value="-1">Please Select Service</option>
                                <?php foreach (getRoomList() as $row ) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['room_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['room_title_en'];?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>


                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Book a site</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">

    </div>

</div>
```

the alert show the write array , but after showing **PataintInfo** div there is vardump($_POST)!

which is not showing any of $_POST array , I think I miss some logic here because the  PataintInfo already loaded when onclick event happen .

Now I want to deal with value of **Cid** using PHP not javascript

Comment: post your PHP code

Comment: What is the filename that all of this is living in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the section if you want to load ajax response on same page.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 toppad">
      <div id="customerFrm">
         <input id="customer_Id" name="customer_Id" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="submit" value="search" onclick="$('#PataintInfo').removeClass('hidden');">Go!</button>
      </div>
      <!-- /form -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
<div id="PataintInfo" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 toppad hidden" >
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Pataint Info</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body" id='contentDiv'>
      <div class="row">
         <div id="customerq_no" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" align="center">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            <table class="table">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Name:</td>
                     <td id="pid"><?php var_dump($_POST)?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Gender</td>
                     <td>Male</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Date of Birth</td>
                     <td>01/24/1988</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Mobile</td>
                     <td>Metro Manila,Philippines</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Service</td>
                     <td>
                        <select id="roomlist">
                           <option value="-1">Please Select Service</option>
                           <?php foreach (getRoomList() as $row ) {
                              ?>
                           <option value="<?php echo $row['room_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['room_title_en'];?></option>
                           <?php
                              }
                              ?>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Book a site</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#PataintInfo').load('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> #contentDiv',{cid: $("#customer_Id").val()});
        return false;
       });

   });
</script>
```

Comment: try to no post code only . try to explain the reasons of your fixes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sorry I stil get ` Notice: Undefined index: cid in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Qnext\Ctrls\newCusotmers.php on line 69`

Comment: you need to check post data.Check keys of post data using print_r($_POST).cid is not exist in post data.